# How to add button in php to swap between files with conditions?

Tags: php

I am on a php project in which students are being asked questions in different levels. I need to display the some part of question in the the combo box. It has 5 levels, a user can view the part of previous question only and not the next question. If all 5 questions are being traversed. Then he/she can view all questions. How and where should I put the code to display like this. I have 5 different files for 5 different questions and one index and login page.

Comment: I am trying to imagine your problem but got confused. Are we talking about 5 pages, each one with one combo? Every page has one piece of the question? Can the user use BACK button to see the previous pieces? How will the user jump to the next page to see the next piece of the question?

Comment: Yes, we got 5 pages. Each page has a question and previous and next button to traverse the questions.
I just need to add a table showing question numbers so that the user can view the questions attempted or un-attempted.

Comment: Explain to me about the questions. What do you mean with "some part of question"? Because I am imaging the question as a long string, and we will split the string in 5 parts, example: "What is | the date | of independence | of our | country?"